# fast scala compiler: Unable to establish connection to compilation daemon

Tags: scala, fsc

I have a ubuntu machine under OpenVZ virtualization. When I run fsc test.scala I get:

`Unable to establish connection to compilation daemon`

Then `ps aux` shows me lots of processes that look like this

```
ren      17482  0.0  0.0   4908  1400 pts/0    S    00:29   0:00 /bin/bash --posix /usr/bin/scala -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true scala.tools
ren      17490  0.2  0.5 1246676 24268 pts/0   Sl   00:29   0:00 java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xbootc
```

I have run out of ideas how to make it work, version is `Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL`. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Found  [this](http://mclear.co.uk/2010/08/20/fsc-could-not-connect-to-compilation-daemon-in-centos/), so:

- selinux is not installed
- export | grep SCALA doesn't return
  anything, however scalac and scala compiling/running fine so I assume
  this step is ok
- ping localhost - works
- fsc -reset - same error
- fsc -verbose >> logfile.log 2>&1 produces this:

> ```
> Fast Scala compiler version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
> [Given arguments: -verbose]
> [Transformed arguments: -verbose -current-dir /home/ren]
> [VM arguments: ]
> [Temp directory: /tmp/scala-devel/ren]
> [Port number: 36737]
> java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
> [Connecting to compilation daemon at port 36737 failed; re-trying...]
> No compile server running: starting one with args ''
> [Executing command: scala scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer -v]
> Starting CompileServer on port 34962
> Redirect dir is /tmp/scala-devel/ren/output-redirects
> [Port number: 34962]
> java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
> [Connecting to compilation daemon at port 34962 failed; re-trying...]
> [Port number: 34962]
> java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
> [Connecting to compilation daemon at port 34962 failed; re-trying...]
> No compile server running: starting one with args '' and so on ...
> ```

**Edit 2:**

Well, starting compilation server like this `scala scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer -v` actually works! And it seems fsc did start all those servers, but for some reason it decided it didn't. `fsc -server localhost:port test.scala` works. Which is good enough for now.

Comment: I experienced a similar error when attempting to `ant build` kafka 0.05. Apparently, I had simply forgotten to install Scala, needed by the compilation step (in my case, Scala 2.8.0.final).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems fsc uses `hostname` to connect to compilation server. My hostname didn't response to ping. Changing it to localhost in `/etc/hostname` fixed the problem.

Comment: You seem to be the only other person who has ever had this issue. Thanks for tracking this down!